# Whats the best way to create dynamic array structure in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have to convert,

```
string1 : "test1.$.test2",
```

into

```
test1:[{
    test2:"{value will be assign later in the code}"
}]
```

I have de structured the string into test1 and test2 using split function, which gives me

- array name = test1
- field name = test2

How do I construct the above format from string? or is there any function in lodash or any npm package I can use?

Comment: Where's your attempt? What have _you_ tried? You should add that code to your question as a [mcve].

Comment: In order to get a good answer, you're going to need to provide more details on the format: Is it _always_ just `A.$.B`, or can it get more complex? As far as I can tell, it's not any well-known format like JSONPath, so there's probably no library that automatically parses that string for you.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `{ [myFieldVariable]: value }` notation as follows:

```
myInput = "test1.$.test2"

fields = myInput.split('.$.'); // ['test1', 'test2']

myObject = {
    [fields[0]]: [ { [fields[1]]: "value assigned later" } ]
};
```

Now doing `console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject, null, '   '))` shows that the object is in the structure you want.

```
{
   "test1": [
      {
         "test2": "value assigned later"
      }
   ]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can [`match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) on `test` followed by a number to return an array of matches, and then use [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#computed_property_names) to build the data structure.

```js
const str = 'test1.$.test2';
const [ first, second ] = str.match(/test\d/g);

const data = {
  [first]: [
    { [second]: '' }
  ]
};

console.log(data);
```

Additional documentation

- [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)